# Dynamic OLEDB Connections in SSIS

Tags: dynamic, ssis, oledbconnection

I am designing a SSIS package which imports data from one data base to other database. In reality I need to import data from **multiple data source to one destination database**. One way to do, that I know is to use package configuration for all data sources (connection strings) and run multiple instances of the same package. But I want something like, I should provide as many connection strings as I need at a point of time in my config file and my package should connect to each database reading data source connection strings from configuration and imports to my destination table.

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Data Flow Task is going to be the same for every data source (e.g. using same table from each data source), you could do something like this:

1. Create an object variable, say ConnStrList. This will hold the list of connection strings.
2. In a script task, loop through your config file and add each connection string to ConnStrList.
3. Add a ForEach loop container, set it's data source to ConnStrList. Create a string variable, say ConnStr. This will hold an individual connection string. Set ConnStr as the iteration variable of the foreach loop.
4. Add your Data Flow Task inside the ForEach loop container.
5. Create an OLEDB connection manager for your OLEDB source. Go to Properties -> Expressions and for ConnectionString, assign the variable ConnStr.

If the DFT is going to be different for each scenario, you might want to have separate data flows for each source.

Please let me know if this answers your question, or if I am getting the scenario wrong.

Comment: You got my question very right. Yes my DFT is same and schema will be same from all the sources so same flow for all the sources. I'll give this a try

Comment: I guess I need to expose the object variable for configuration and read the same in a Script task and then break the different connection strings?

Comment: Yes you will need to read in all connection strings from config file into your Script Task then add them to a list and use that list as source of ForEach.

Comment: ConnStrList are you referring this to some component?

Comment: Ya. This one needs to be the source of ForEach loop.

Comment: which component it would be? Sorry I couldn't find one

Comment: Which one are you not able to find? In ForEach loop you need to select Variable enumerator type.

Comment: Actually I never used ForEach container before.I'll explore this.Thanks. Looks like your approach will work for me.